# React Native TypeError: Network request failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch

```
const REQUEST_URI_TEST = "https://test.huheyoudi.net/douyou/rest";
const REQUEST_URI = "https://www.huheyoudi.net/douyou/rest";

var uri = REQUEST_URI + "/logon/15850760706?current_logon_device=MI4&password=qwer1234";
fetch(uri, {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
})
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(json => {
    console.log(json);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Use the REQUEST_URI_TEST will cause an exception. and I cannot catch any error in catch area, I can see the log by react native tool iin chrome.

```
TypeError: Network request failed
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (E:\WorkSpace\01.ReactNative\DouYouRN\node_modules\whatwg-fetch\fetch.js:441)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (E:\WorkSpace\01.ReactNative\DouYouRN\node_modules\event-target-shim\lib\event-target.js:172)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (E:\WorkSpace\01.ReactNative\DouYouRN\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:567)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (E:\WorkSpace\01.ReactNative\DouYouRN\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:397)
    at E:\WorkSpace\01.ReactNative\DouYouRN\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:503
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (E:\WorkSpace\01.ReactNative\DouYouRN\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:179)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (E:\WorkSpace\01.ReactNative\DouYouRN\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:351)
    at E:\WorkSpace\01.ReactNative\DouYouRN\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:116
    at MessageQueue.__guardSafe (E:\WorkSpace\01.ReactNative\DouYouRN\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:314)
    at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (E:\WorkSpace\01.ReactNative\DouYouRN\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:115)
```

but the REQUEST_URI can login correctlly!

I donnot know the reason, and both 2 URI can be access by postman. Does anybody can give me some advises?

Comment: Do you have internet on your device/simulator?

Comment: I have run this code into a real Android device